# How to merge iCalendar events

Tags: php, algorithm, icalendar

I'm trying to merge multiple iCalendars together. I wanna be able to merge overlapping events. So for example, if I have an event Monday at 12pm - 2pm and another event at 1pm - 3pm, I want to end up with an event that runs from 12pm until 3pm.

I'm looking for a simple open-source script that does that in PHP, or just help with the algorithm itself.

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: are the two calendars you want to merge having the same events at different times? in other words do they share the same uid or are you just looking for ways to merge any overlapping events (in which case the question would be : what should the uid, description, summary properties be)

Comment: For the parsing part, the vobject library may help: https://github.com/evert/sabre-vobject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing if anyone's interested. It may not be the most efficient, but it's good enough for what I'm doing.

1. Parse the calendars into Event objects (each object has a start time and end time unix timestamps), the class Event should also have a toString() method for exporting.
2. Store all objects in an array then sort it by start time (ascendingly)
3. Initialize an array for the final result, let's call it "final_array"
4. Take the first Event in the array as "A"
5. Start iterating through the array starting with the next Event, let's name it "B"

   1. If B starts after A ends: Add A to final_array and make B the new A
   2. If B starts before A ends:

      1. If B ends before A ends: Do nothing
      2. If B ends after A ends: Change A's end time to B's end time.
6. Go back to 5 if you haven't reached the end of the array
7. For each event in final_array, write event to the new calendar file

Answer (score 1):

Right -- sadly, I cannot help you with the PHP coding, as i know nothing of PHP (this also means my algorithmic help might just be waay off). However, I know quite my way around algorithms, so I'm going to come up with as many as possible. I'll give each it's reasons for and against, you can take your pick, and hopefully we'll both learn something.

First off, a simplification -- note that when merging more than two ICalendars together, we can merge two, then merge our result with the next etc; meaning our algorithm can just merge two to work.

With that in mind, the conceptually simplest merge I can muster:

1. Given ICalendars A and B, we will merge them into a new ICalendar C
2. Initialize C
3. Pick & remove the earliest event from either A or B, adding it to C.
4. Do the same, this time "merging the events" if they overlap.
5. lather, rinse, repeat until both A and B are empty -- C should now contain the merger of A and B.

Actually, this would be close to the best algorithm -- *O(n)* time, where n is the average number of events per ICalendar; meaning no other methods will be forthcoming...sadly.